# Set userPassword to {CRYPT-SHA-512} in OpenLDAP programmaticaly remotely?

Tags: php, openldap

I'm trying to set a OpenLDAP userPassword to CRYPT-SHA-512 remotely. I would prefer to do this in PHP, but I'm open to other solutions that can be executed via PHP (e.g. python).

It's easy to set the userPassword to SHA1 remotely by setting the userPassword = `'{SHA}'.base64_encode(sha1($password, true))`.

How would you do this for CRYPT-SHA-512 password?

I would assume the checker would have to use the same crypt and number of rounds.

```
<?php
  $rounds = 5000; //??
  $salt = random_seventeen_char();
  $userPassword = '{CRYPT}'.crypt($password, '$6$rounds='.$rounds.'$'.salt.'$');
?>
```

I am able to do this through Apache Directory Studio without issues but need to be able to do it via a script.

Comment: why not just use `password_hash()` and do away with salting; or are you limited to using this from a 3rd party application?

Comment: so; left the question or was that ^ just a stupid/silly comment on my part? Edit: Ok I left.

Comment: $hashes['userPassword'] = '{CRYPT-SHA-512}'.password_hash($password, CRYPT_SHA512); does not work either. I'm guessing the salts and rounds aren't matching up to what OpenLDAP likes. It sets the bind type BUT authentication does not work, which would indicate a failed hash check.

Comment: That isn't how `password_hash()` works; see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php - Given if you want to use it. And if so, `password_verify()` is what to use to verify it with http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: I'm doing the same thing as https://searchcode.com/file/46673833/mail/plugins/password/drivers/ldap.php (scroll to bottom) but want to set to a '{CRYPT-SHA-512}' value which is accepted the OpenLDAP build.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify the rounds in OpenLDAP BINDPW. Here is the solution:

```
function randomSalt( $length ) {
        $possible = '0123456789'.
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.
                './';
        $str = '';
        // mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);

        while (strlen($str) < $length)
                $str .= substr($possible, (rand() % strlen($possible)), 1);

        return $str;
}

$hashes['userPassword'] = '{CRYPT}'.crypt($this->pass, '$6$'.randomSalt(16).'$');
```

Comment: Also, although it is saved as a 'CRYPT-SHA-512' it is specified in bindpw as '{CRYPT}'

Comment: According to [crypt() doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.crypt.php), shouldn't you generate a random salt of 16 characters to use SHA-512 ?

Comment: Updated @ZalemCitizen